# Getting two different errors when running teradeep demo, libthnets.so is missing

Tags: opencv, compilation, camera, webcam, luarocks

I was attempting to install the [teradeep/demo-apps](https://github.com/teradeep/demo-apps) to experiment with, and have hit a roadblock.

After unpacking, I was presented with three folders: `opencv`, `generic-pc`, and `generic-embedded`. After compiling the two generic folders, I attempted to run all three,  and all three failed.

When I try to run `generic-pc`, it gives me:

```
Number of threads used: 8
qlua: ./frame.lua:63: module 'linuxcamera' not found:
    no field package.preload['linuxcamera']
    no file '/home/dave/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/linuxcamera.lua'
    no file '/home/dave/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/linuxcamera/init.lua'
    no file '/home/dave/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/linuxcamera.lua'
    no file '/home/dave/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/linuxcamera/init.lua'
    no file './linuxcamera.lua'
    no file '/home/dave/torch/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-alpha/linuxcamera.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/linuxcamera.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/linuxcamera/init.lua'
    no file '/home/dave/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/linuxcamera.so'
    no file '/home/dave/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/linuxcamera.so'
    no file './linuxcamera.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/linuxcamera.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x7fcb5d5a1970
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./frame.lua:63: in function 'prep_lua_linuxcamera'
    ./frame.lua:86: in function 'init'
    run.lua:102: in main chunk
```

And when I try to run the `opencv` and `generic-embedded` folders, it gives me:

```
: error while loading shared libraries: libthnets.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What would be the best way to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to work properly on linux, the demo app needs a specially compiled library called `linuxcamera` provided with the demo app. You will need to compile it and store it in your `/home/dave/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/` folder.

First, go to the `lib` folder in `generic-pc` and edit the `Makefile` file so it looks like this (you can just copy and replace everything, only things changed are the paths to the libs folder):

```
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
UNAME_P := $(shell uname -p)
LBITS := $(shell getconf LONG_BIT)

INCLUDE = -I. -I/usr/local/include -I$(HOME)/torch/install/include
LIBOPTS = -shared -L$(HOME)/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1 -L$(HOME)/torch/install/lib
CFLAGS = -O3 -c -fpic -Wall
LINUXCAMERA_FILES = linuxcamera.o videocap.o
LIBFILES = linuxcamera.so
CC = gcc

ifneq ($(filter arm%,$(UNAME_P)),)
    CFLAGS += -mfpu=neon
endif

.PHONY : all
all : $(LIBFILES)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $<

linuxcamera.so : $(LINUXCAMERA_FILES)
    $(CC) $(LINUXCAMERA_FILES) $(LIBOPTS) -o $@

install : $(LIBFILES)
    sudo cp $(LIBFILES) $(HOME)/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/

uninstall :
    sudo rm $(HOME)/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/linuxcamera.so

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -f *.o $(LIBFILES)
```

Then, [as documented](https://github.com/teradeep/demo-apps/tree/master/generic-pc#install), run `make clean; make; make install;`

This should compile and copy the library in the `lib` folder for your `qlua` runtime. You should now be able to run `qlua run.lua` and it should load the library properly.